# Why isn't my char* passing correctly?

Tags: c

**Problem statement** (using a contrived example):

Working as expected ('b' is printed to screen):

```
void Foo(const char* bar);

void main()
{
    const char bar[4] = "bar";
    Foo(bar);
}

void Foo(const char* bar)
{
    // Pointer to first text cell of video memory
    char* memory = (char*) 0xb8000;
    *memory = bar[0];
}
```

Not working as expected (`\0` is printed to screen):

```
void Foo(const char* bar);

void main()
{
    Foo("bar");
}

void Foo(const char* bar)
{
    // Pointer to first text cell of video memory
    char* memory = (char*) 0xb8000;
    *memory = bar[0];
}
```

In other words, if I pass the `const char*` directly, it doesn't pass correctly.  The `const char*` I get in `Foo` points to zeroed out memory somehow.  What am I doing wrong?

**Background info** (as requested):

I am developing an operating system for fun, using a guide I found [here](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~exr/lectures/opsys/10_11/lectures/os-dev.pdf). The guide generally assumes you are on a unix-based machine, but I'm developing on a PC, so I'm using MinGW so that I have access to gcc, ld, etc.
In the guide, I am currently on page 54, where you have just bootstrapped your custom kernel. Rather than simply displaying an 'X' as the guide teaches, I decided to use my existing knowledge of C/C++ to attempt to write my own rudimentary print string function.  The function is supposed to take a `const char*` and write it, char by char, into video memory.
Three files are currently involved in the project:

- The boot sector - compiled through NASM to a .bin file
- The kernel entry routine - compiled without linking through NASM to a .o, linked against the kernel
- The kernel - compiled through gcc, linked along with the kernel entry routine through the ld command, which produces a .bin which is appended to the .bin file produced by the boot sector

Once the combined .bin file is generated, I am converting it to .VDI (VirtualBox Disk Image) and running it in a VM I have set up.

**Additional info**:

I just noticed that when VirtualBox is converting the .bin file to .vdi, it is reporting different sizes for the two examples. I had a hunch that maybe the string was getting omitted entirely from the compiled product. Sure enough, when I look at .bin for the first example in a hex editor, I can find the text "bar", but I can't when I look at a hex dump for the .bin of the second example.

This leads me to believe that the compilation process I'm using has a flaw in it somewhere. Here are the commands I'm using:

```
nasm boot_sector.asm -f bin -o boot_sector.bin
nasm kernel_entry.asm -f elf -o kernel_entry.o
gcc -ffreestanding -c kernel.c -o kernel.o
ld -T NUL -o kernel.tmp -Ttext 0x1000 kernel_entry.o kernel.o
objcopy -O binary -j .text kernel.tmp kernel.bin
copy /b boot_sector.bin+kernel.bin os_image.bin
```

os_image.bin is what is converted to the .vdi file which is used in the vm.

Comment: What is str inside foo?

Comment: what is str and where are you printing ?

Comment: Running in windows.  Compiled using gcc and ld through MinGW.  There's a possibility that some of my command line options for ld aren't correct, but most code runs fine...

Comment: With the `const char[]` thing, the compiler (most likely) will not need the `.rodata` section - the char values are plugged directly in the code. With the other version, the `.rodata` section is needed. You'll need to show more of your build setup. (And how are you running the code?)

Comment: I added more details about what's going on.  If you have specific questions, I'd be happy to add more details above.

Comment: I would first try to copy the char to some allocated dynamic memory, just to ensure that the problem is not about stack/pointers/etc. Another think - could it be that "someone" overrides your memory before you print it... ?

Comment: *groan....I'm at a low enough level that I don't even have access to the C runtime.  If I want to dynamically allocate memory, I'll have to implement `malloc`....

Comment: What happens if you try `Foo((const char*) "bar");` in your `main`?

Comment: Same thing. I found out an interesting difference between the two examples which I detailed above, though.

Comment: You're only copying the `.text` section. Strings will be in the `.rodata` section.

Comment: Aaahhhhhhhhh of course. I just needed to remove the -j option. Wow. You're my hero. If you write that up as an answer I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With your first example, the compiler will (or at least, can) put the data to initialize the automatic array right in the code (`.text` section - moves with immediate values are used when I try this out).

With your second example, the string literal is put in the `.rodata` section, and the code will contain a reference to that section.

Your `objcopy` command only copies the `.text` section, so the string will be missing in the final binary. You should add the `.rodata` section, or remove the `-j .text` entirely.